# How do I grant OpenSearch users Dev Tools read permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

I'm trying to give read permission to OpenSearch users on AWS, users can access but can't see anything in side menu, only DashBoard option and DevTools doesn't appear.
I'm using AWS groups.

I tried to create new roles adding index permissions and also tried to add the all_access role permission just for testing and it didn't work, but when adding the security_manager role, all options appear, but I don't want to allow access to the security.

Also tried to add few permissions 
opensearch_dashboards_user 
opensearch_dashboards_read_only